# CSS - strange browser issues with 100% width fluid layout, why?

Tags: css, xhtml

OK, so if you go check out http://furnace.howcode.com you'll see the example. [The site is in active development so pardon the mess/comments between devs ;) ]

**To recreate the issue:** Click the 'Top Rated' tab. Click the 'PHP Array Looping' result (it's the best example. Note that data is fetched via Ajax and may take a moment to load).

In the third column space the entry will be returned*.

Despite the fact that the total widths of `#col1 + #col2 + #col3 = 100%`, the browser still adds a kind of 30px margin to the right. Presumably this is where a scrollbar would go but if is there any way to reliably fill that space? Sadly `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body tag makes no difference.

---

**I have a further issue** which I presume is related to the problem here. I want the `#col3` result to have `padding-left: 10px;` applied. Now in the box model I understand that padding does not alter the space outside but rather the space inside - sadly when I set `padding-left: 10px;` to `#col3` it disappears off the page. It's late, I'm tired and have hit a caffeine low but I can't work out why...! :)

Thanks, really appreciate the help! Browsers I've tested on: Google Chrome, Firefox 3.6 (both on Mac)

Jack

.

**sorry for the hideous styling, we've completely rethought the design and I haven't been able to restyle it yet)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have max-width set for the 3 columns:

```
#col1
    max-width: 124px
#col2
    max-width: 529px
#col3
    max-width: 729px
```

these are set in http://furnace.howcode.com/scaffold/index.php?f=/stylesheets/master.css from row 349.

I suggest you check with "Inspect Element" in Google Chrome - there you easily can change the CSS on the fly to try out and see if it is overwritten with any other style as I guess is happening with your padding.